# How to derive a diffusion tensor and stationary states given a Markov process transition matrix?

Tags: markov-chains, matlab, markov-process

Let the transition matrix $P_{ij}$ represents the probability to move from state $i$ to state $j$.

Now I would like to derive the diffusion tensor for this Markov process.

Since I am not sure how to start for the general case, I am taking a $3 \times 3$ matrix as an example:
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} &  \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can derive the diffusion coefficient $D$ assuming time step $\Delta t$. First we assume a 1D random walk with the probability $0.5$ to stay at the same spot and $0.25$ to move $\pm1 \Delta x$:

$$
\begin{align*}
X(x,t+\Delta t)-X(x,t) &= \frac{1}{4} (X(x+\Delta X,t)+ X(x-\Delta X,t)) - \frac{1}{2} X(x,t) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} (X(x-\Delta X,t)+ X(x+\Delta X,t) - 2X(x,t))
\end{align*}
$$

Where $X$ is the probability to be at $x$ at time $t$.

When taking the space between $\Delta x \to 0$, $\Delta t \to 0$ and dividing by $\Delta t$:

$$
\frac{X(x,t+\Delta t)-X(x,t)}{\Delta t} = \left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x} \right)^2\frac {\frac{1}{4} (X(x-\Delta X,t)+ X(x+\Delta X,t) - 2X(x,t))}{\Delta t}
$$

We get the diffusion equation:

$$
\frac{\partial X}{\partial t} = \frac{(\Delta x)^2}{4 \Delta t} \frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial^2 x}
$$

Where $D=\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{4 \Delta t}$

Or back to the discrete case $D=1/4$ in unit less dimensions.

Could I achieve a diffusion tensor for a general $P_{ij}$ transition Markov process matrix.

Calculating the stationary matrix:  $\lim_{k \to \infty} P^k = \lim_{k \to \infty} \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} &  \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix} ^k
$

Which means our [stationary states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix#Definition_and_properties) are to be anywhere see the Matlab code:

```
>> a=[1/2 1/4 1/4; 1/4 1/2 1/4; 1/4 1/4 1/2 ]

a =

    0.5000    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.5000    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.5000

>> a^1e99

ans =

     0.3333     0.3333     0.3333
     0.3333     0.3333     0.3333
     0.3333     0.3333     0.3333
```

Comment: Don't do `P^inf`, try `P^n` for larger and larger values of `n`, the result will converge to a matrix of 1/3'rds.